# Which is the best way to implement multiple list?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, android, lists

I want to build an android app. In this app user can pick a student from a school, for this user must pass through school > standards > division > student. How can I make a best picker for picking students easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a pretty deep hierarchy, though you haven't given a specific use-case.

Normally, you're better of having a `STUDENT` section then have `school`, `standards`, `division` as FILTER. Filters help you easily pick specific information from a large dataset

Comment: how can i implement a best filter for this.i want more flexible  ui in less space.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering that there are multiple schools to choose from as it’s not clear from question, however solution for having one school in case will not be far distinct from this.
There can be multiple cases to handle I am listing major three:
User know the name of student for whom he is looking for but doesn’t know the school or standard or section
User doesn’t know the name, he just wants to see the list of students in any school’s std. and than pick a student based on some traits or achievements
User know the name of student as well as school, class and standard

If the case is 1:
Search can be very powerful in this kind of scenario. User can not start finding by selecting a school as he is not aware about school or in case he is aware, he might not be clear about class or section and vice-versa. Using search he can simply type the name of student and will get the result with their details which should be comprised of school, standard and section (or anything else which is important in your scenario). Filter pattern will play a vital role in this scenario to refine the results and get more accurate information. User should have the power to filter result based on school, standard and section (Having filter section can be a really difficult case to handle as different schools can have different way to denote section).

If the case is 2:
One way to achieve objective in this case can be classical way where user select a school then standard and so on to pick a student (Make sure to have a breadcrumb or some kind of components to make sure at which level user is right now in navigation, if you are planning something like this). But I believe pattern like this is not so useful if you have large number of schools in a list. Its better to add a functionality in search where user can select/type any trait, quality or anything which you are planning to have in your database about student and give results based on that and then user can refine it based on filter criteria school, standard, division etc. For e.g.: if user enter basketball user will be able to see a list of all students those someway have enrolled themselves in to basketball game and then user can refine the results.

If the case is 3:
User can pretty easily achieve the objective by selecting school from the list and than narrow down scope by selecting standard and section.

I would recommend to have both the patterns keeping in mind that all user may not like to search in case 3 they might want to go through complete navigation.